# Query so slow on 3M records. Suggest any kind of optimization

Tags: mysql

First of all, I'm sorry for the disorganized and confusing structure. It was decided by the previous team, and now I have to handle it all.

`salesman_master` `300 records`

| salesman_id | salesman_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Salesman 1 |
| 2 | Salesman 2 |

`client_master` `9000 records`

| client_id | client_name | pricing_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | Client 2 | 1025 |

`salesman_access` `Upto 4000 client/salesman`

| id | client_id | salesman_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

`pricing_group` `100 records`

| id | pricing_group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | XYZ Prices |
| 1025 | ABC Prices |

`pricing_detail_master` `Upto 1000 sku/pricing_group`

| id | pricing_group | sku | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 12033 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 1000 | 12038 | 200.00 |
| 1 | 1025 | 12033 | 300.00 |
| 2 | 1025 | 12038 | 400.00 |

`prd_acc` `3M records`

| id | client_id | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12033 |
| 2 | 1 | 12038 |
| 3 | 2 | 12033 |
| 4 | 2 | 12038 |

This is the query I'm trying to run. Now I have tried setting indexes on required columns for all of these tables but somehow query some times takes 30-40 seconds and some times it give error `MySQL Server has gone away`.

Please give any kind of structural or optimization advice, any kind of suggestion needed. Thanks

```
 SELECT * FROM 
   salesman_access sa 
 JOIN 
   client_master cm ON sa.client_id = cm.client_id 
 JOIN 
   pricing_detail_master pdm ON pdm.pricing_group = cm.pricing_group 
 JOIN
   prd_acc pa ON pa.client_id = cm.client_id 
 WHERE 
   sa.salesman_id = 202
```

[fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49KQ5WnQubCU45YD8D4KXa/0)

Comment: Did you try running EXPLAIN query for that in the first place ????? What is the expected result rowcount number?

Comment: What MySQL version? What did the server error log say?

Comment: Your description is lacking some columns, eg sa.client_master_id. Please fix this quetsion to include actual structure etc. Prepare small db example eg here 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/ using REAL CREATE TABLE statements so we can try to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Antoniossss Expected result rowcount is around 800-900.

Comment: @VivekMakwana prepare db filldle and we will see. Using real schema (i mean 5 tables involved here) is the best option

Comment: Give me a minute

Comment: @Antoniossss [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49KQ5WnQubCU45YD8D4KXa/0) It won't let me use group by because of `only_full_group_by`

Comment: Can you share what's the expected result? What do you want to get with your extraction?

Comment: @VivekMakwana Fiddle starts looking good. You didnt include any indexes there. Now, do you have NO INDEXES DEFINED at all on the real DB? If so, it is not going to be any faster without indexes for non primary colums. If you have those, include them in the fiddle as well. Right now you are doing complete search on every table

Comment: @VivekMakwana run EXPLAIN query and paste the result like here
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cohtDwyLftmtimXyRxiMTF/0

Comment: prd_acc, salesman_access have no indexes, this impacts hugely on the performance of the joins

Comment: I have set required indexes on all tables just haven't defined on fiddle

Comment: @VivekMakwana I see no indexes here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/49KQ5WnQubCU45YD8D4KXa/0

Comment: Can you put the exact DDL you are using on your DB? The indexes on the JOIN columns should be enough to speed up all the query

Comment: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cohtDwyLftmtimXyRxiMTF/2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cohtDwyLftmtimXyRxiMTF/2)

Comment: What's the selectivity of indexed columns used in join condition? Can we have the `show index` result (for cardinality) and the row count for each table? As you use `select *` rather than querying for specific columns, MySQL will have to use the PK as a pointer to reference the whole table. When this happens, if the selectivity of the secondary index is low, MySQL may prefer a table scan to secondary index loopup/scan.

Comment: Besides, are all columns in all the joined tables really required? `SELECT *` can be a disaster especially in table joining. More often than not, `SELECT *` is executed and passed to application side, which only use part of the dataset and discard the rest. And the `select list` can also affect how MySQL decides which or if an index should be used unless all the items in the `select clause` are covered in an index (covering index)

Comment: Since the required info for further analyzing is missing. The best advice I can give is DEFINITELY AVOID a full table scan on the prd_acc table (3M rows examined are disastrous) , and try to narrow down the `SELECT LIST` for columns which you actually need.

Comment: Explain says no idexes are almost used but thats probbably doe to low selectivity of indexes in small tiny dataset. Run `EXPLAIN` and share results

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do a subquery with the huge table and the tables which have the most direct way for the condition.
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  prd_acc pa
JOIN
  salesman_access sa ON pa.client_id = pa.client_id
WHERE 
   sa.salesman_id = 202
```

This way you reduce the 3M to the expected 800-900 records, and with these you annex all the remaining columns

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT sa.* FROM 
    prd_acc pa
  JOIN
    salesman_access sa ON pa.client_id = pa.client_id
  WHERE 
    sa.salesman_id = 202 ) AS tps
JOIN
  client_master cm ON tps.client_id = cm.client_id 
JOIN 
  pricing_detail_master pdm ON pdm.pricing_group = cm.pricing_group
```

Not sure if `salesman_master` was ommited on purpose, but you can annex it.

Comment: Unfortunately same error `Server gone away`. I don't understand why it happens. I know 3M records are not huge deal

Comment: Then maybe you have to tweak the settings of your MYSQL server, starting with the config (my.ini) on entries like innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M or join_buffer_size=256K or tmp_table_size=162M and put more usage of RAM. Also depending on the type of tables they are.

Comment: Maybe another thing might be to check the physical device where the mysql DB files are stored. If they are in a HDD change them to a SSD, crank up the values of the memory usage in the config file, and if necessary improve the physical memory of the machine serving the DB.

Comment: Actually it's on godaddy shared hosting. I don't think you can change these config

Comment: For a DB with that amount of records maybe you are exceeding the capabilities of a shared hosting.

Comment: Last thing you might try to do is increase the max execution time the script is allowed to have. So it can wait for the query to finish. If you are using PHP try ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); and see how much you can put it.

Comment: I personally think that query planner  will do far better job in optimizing query couple of joins then using subqueries as it can rather make things go worse. (and I cannot explain your query as it ends up with an error)

Comment: updated the query so it doesn't throw the dup id error

Answer (score 0):

this could be due to several things!

1. How Much RAM or Disc Space du you have (free Spaces)? Is it Enoth?
2. Do you have set a limit for the RAM-Usage?
3. Look carefully on the Indexes which you
   set! Maybe you set a Index on a Unique Index Key? In this case The
   indexes "destroys" each other!

More information would be helpful. They are also a Query-Analyzser for Mysql did you try it with them?